# Cruisecontrol.NET & IIS7 Static File Handler Problem

Tags: iis-7, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to get Cruisecontrol.NET running with Server 2008/IIS7 and when I try and navigate to the dashboard I get the following error:
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

I'm a bit lost in IIS7 so it could be something pretty straightforward. They (cc.net) do some funny stuff with http handlers in the web.config which may be related to the problem:

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Is the dashboard set up as an application in IIS?

I've not used IIS7, but I know in IIS6 you need to enable an application and assign it to an app pool before you can run ASPX code.

**EDIT:**  This works in IIS6.

Open the IISAdmin tool on the web server.  Expand the web sites folder. Find the virtual directory (directories?) for CruiseControl.  Right-click on it and look at properties.  On the directory tab, create a new application and give it a suitable name.  Enable the application to execute "scripts only".  Assign it to an application pool (you may want to create a new one just for this application -- consult the help documentation for this).  You may also need to change the ASP.NET version   You can do this on the ASP.NET tab -- choose either v1.1 or v2.0, whichever CruiseControl requires.

Comment: Yes it is. I think I might need to change a setting somewhere in IIS that allows it to execute scripts but have no idea where it is.

Comment: Thanks tvanfosson. That sounds like it is exactly what I need to do. Can't work out how to do it in IIS7 though. I reinstalled CC.NET and it worked this time (I must have done something different).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In Vista, go to Windows features in the control panel.  there is a section there for IIS and you will find the scripting setting under the IIS 6 compatibility section

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue when I installed CCNET 1.5 under Windows 7/IIS 7.5

You need to configure the app pool for the ccnet site. Under the Basic Settings for the application pool, set 'Managed pipeline mode' to 'Integrated'.

Comment: Thank you very much Babak! That sovled the issue for me too on Win Server 2008 r2 with IIS7 (II6 management compatibility installed)